# Parsing PDF Document with ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Looking for a way to parse a PDF (with just text in it), into the plain text.  I see that PDF parsing with Ruby has been asked before but the answers are several years old, and not suited to a rails app.

Is there a gem that can assist with this?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the [docsplit gem](http://documentcloud.github.io/docsplit/) is all about. Usage example:

```
pdfs = Dir['storage/originals/*.pdf']
Docsplit.extract_text(pdfs, :ocr => false)
```

Whats great with this gem is that it can convert `.doc` or `.odt` etc... to get the text.

Plus it's backed by a very specialised company: http://www.documentcloud.org/

Comment: The last line sounds like an advertisement. I'd recommend removing it.

Comment: well no, document cloud, or namely Jeremy Ashkenas, did docsplit, coffeescript and backbone, sounds pretty good... just recognition of job done

Comment: Knowing a reference business relies on a gem is a great sign of quality, or at least I feel like it is

Comment: If it is indeed a very specialized company, then it is factual.  If the statement were opinionated, then I would agree to remove it.  If it were a slogan, also.  I see nothing wrong with stating the factual backing of a company that is factually described.

Comment: can `docsplit gem` parse a table with tabular data in it effectively ?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader/tree/master) seems to be quite famous. I haven't tried it but it seems relevant.